# How to use tkdiff to compare two gzip files in gui mode?

Tags: linux, diff

How to use tkdiff to compare  two gzip files in gui mode?

Answer (score 0):

If your shell supports it, you can use process substitution...

```
tkdiff <(gzip -dc file1.gz) <(gzip -dc file2.gz)
```

Now `tkdiff` will think the files are called something like `/dev/fd/4` and `/dev/fd/5` but the contents of those two files will be the uncompressed files, and so will operate normally.